# Should return type of a function and its type as argument be the same?

Tags: c++, lambda, pass-by-reference

[Here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/08/03/hello-lambdas-c-0x-a-quick-guide-to-lambdas-in-c) I found this piece of the code (and I have modified it a bit):

```
template<typename F>     
void Eval( const F& f ) {
     f(3.14);
}
```

As far as I understand the Eval function takes another function as argument and return its value for a particular value of its argument (3.14 in the above case). But I am not sure what should be used as type of the function? Its return type? So, should it be called in the following way?:

```
Eval<float>(sin)
```

Moreover, why do we use pointers (&-symbol)? Do we pass argument by reference because we want to change it? Do we want to redefine function inside the `Eval` function? If yes, why we do no do that? If not, why we do we need the & symbol?

Comment: `&` is not a pointer here, it means the `F` instance is passed by reference. Constant reference due to the `const`. So you get an alias to whatever was passed from the caller side. And you cannot modify that instance via the reference.

Comment: your function returns `void`, whatever is `F`.

Answer (score 3):

`Eval` is a function template. A function instantiated from this template has return type `void`, which means it doesn't return a value. It simply calls `f(3.14)` internally and then returns to the caller.

Its parameter is of type *constant reference to type `F`,* where `F` is the template parameter. Passing by const-reference means that you cannot modify the object inside the function, but *no copy is made.* Inside the function `f` will just be a different name for the object (or function) passed in.

`Eval` obviously expects its argument to be a callable type: a function, a pointer to function or an object of a class which defines `operator()`. So you cannot specify the template argument as `double`. If anything, it should be `double(double)` = function taking a double and returning a double. Most of the time, though, you shouldn't have to specify the template argument at all: it will be deduced from the actual argument you pass in. Like this:

```
void myFun(double x)
{
  std::cout << x << '\n';
}

void someFun()
{
  Eval(myFun);
  Eval([](double a){ global_var = a; });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> But I am not sure what should be used as type of the function?

Function types look like `float(float)`.

Or do you mean the return type? In modern C++, you could infer the return type:

```
template <typename F>
auto Eval(const F & f) -> decltype(f(3.14)) {
    return f(3.14);
}
```

If you're stuck with an older version of the language, then it's rather trickier. You could provide overloads for plain functions, and for function types that contain a `result_type` definition (such as those derived from `std::unary_function`):

```
template <typename Ret, typename Arg>
Ret eval(Ret (&f)(Arg)) {return f(3.14);}

template <typename F>
typename F::result_type eval(F const & f) {return f(3.14);}
```

perhaps generalising this by defining a traits class, or using [Boost's function traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html)

> So, should it be called in the following way?

If there's only one function with that name, you can use argument-dependent lookup:

```
Eval(sin);
```

However, if this is `std::sin`, then there are multiple overloads so you will have to specify the type:

```
Eval<float(float)>(sin);
```

> Moreover, why do we use pointers (&-symbol)?

We don't. That's a reference, not a pointer.

> Do we pass argument by reference because we want to change it?

No. It's a reference to `const`, so we can't change it.

> If not, why we do we need the & symbol?

Some types are expensive to copy; others can't be copied at all; but all types can be passed by reference. So a completely generic function template needs to take its argument by reference in order to be usable for all types.

Comment: Technical point, [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is generic, yet it takes its function object by value; in fact, all `std` algorithms take the function object by value.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: Indeed; they're not completely generic, since they require that the function object be copyable (or movable).

Comment: The compiler can self pick sin(double) ? We need to write Eval<float(float)>(sin); only if we want float, or for double we need too?

Comment: @qPCR4vir: You'll need to specify `double(double)` if you want that overload. If the function is overloaded and the compiler can't figure out which overload you mean, it will give an error rather than choosing one arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing something that is a **callable type** which means that it's either a `std::function<double(double)>` or a  function pointer that points to a function `(double)(fooptr*)(double)` or a class/struct which as `doubule operator()(double)` overloaded so that it can be called like it were a function.

The fact that you have a `f()`  inside your `Eval` gives you the clue that any type that is passed to `F` should be callable with `()`

Here is an example of you could use it:

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename F>     
void Eval( const F& f ) {
    std::cout << f(3.14);
}

double foo(double d)
{
   return d + d;
}
int main()
{

 Eval(foo);
}
```

[Live Example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2SZDri%243)

Comment: Wong. It should be `Eval(foo)`. The compiler knows best!

Comment: Hmm, and what if f return something for what there is not an overload of << ?

Comment: Then you'd have to write you own `operator<<(std::ostream& os, someobj obj)` overload.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ templates are instantiated during compilation, so if you pass anything, that supports calling, it will work.

For example:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void operator() (double d)
    {
        // Do something
    } 
}

MyClass m;

Eval(m);
```

Or:

```
Eval([](double d) { /* ... */ });
```

Or:

```
void DoSth(double d)
{
    // ...
}

Eval(DoSth);
```

Why do we pass by const references? There are a few reasons:

- Passed object is not copied, what increases performance;
- You cannot pass non-existing object (references cannot be null)
- const in a const reference assures, that the object itself won't be changed inside function call

Comment: Here operator() have to be defined as const ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to return the value, you would want to use something like this

```
template<typename F>     
typename F::result_type Eval(F f) {
     return f(3.14);
}
```

#### Notes

1. It is more idiomatic to pass functions by value.
2. This may not work with a `void` return type.
3. The function must be [adaptable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_%28C%2B%2B%29#Adaptable_function_objects).
4. You don't need to pass template parameters as the compiler can work it out for itself.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I understand the Eval function takes another function as
>   argument and return its value

No, `Eval` return void. Whatever `f(3.14)` return is not used.

> But I am not sure what should be used as type of the function? Its
>   return type? So, should it be called in the following way?:
>   `Eval<float>(sin)`

In most cases `Eval(obj)` will be sufficient, and the type `F` will be "deduced" from the type of `obj`. IF that is ambiguos you will need to be explicit:  `Eval<float(float)>(sin)`(I hofe you included the rigth header file). Any "object" of the type that can be "called" with an `double` argument will compile.

```
Moreover, why do we use pointers (&-symbol)?
```

No. here `const` and `&` mean const reference. You acces directly the argument, but promise not to change it.